Shiur for Al Hamichya
What is the minimum shiur to say Al Hamichya? If one eats a quantity of mezonos which is less than the shiur, should they say Borei Nefashos instead?

The minimum shiur for Al Hamichya and Borei Nefashos (depending on the food) is a k'zayis, or the amount of an olive. The exact measurement of that amount in ounces is subject to dispute.

Should one make a point to specifically eat the amount of the shiur? Like is it problematic to just eat less and not say a bracha achrona?

No. But if you are in the gray area of maybe a k'zayis maybe not, you should eat more. Consult your rav for a p'sak in terms of amounts.

In terms of the shiur, my Rav sent me the following message. We assume that kzayis for bracha achrona is based upon the smaller shiur. The shiur is 27 grams or like 1oz (eaten within 4 mins). I have trouble knowing these amounts based upon foods but as an example I looked online at chips ahoys cookies and it says on the nutrition facts that 3 cookies is 33 grams so that would be like 2.5 cookies for Al hamichya.
